# Using an if statement followed with a call doesn't seem to work in a batch file

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I have the following line of code in a batch file, named DriveBackup for now:

```
if %1%NOTSET==NOTSET call :finish 4
```

If the input parameter is not set/given, I call the finished routine.  I'm trying to pass in an error code (in this case, 4) so that the finished routine spits out a useful error message before the batch file terminates.  I get this (echo is on)...

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop>DriveBackup
4 was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop>if finish 4
C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop>
```

The following line in its place works....  `if %1%NOTSET==NOTSET goto donothing`  (a no-op)

It looks like the "call" is dropping out.  How am I doing the call improperly? Can you not use an if condition to trigger a call? The finish routine is within the batch file itself. It's not a call to another batch file.

Comment: Parameters only have a leading `%` instead of one on both sides. Also, it's better to use quotes rather than other text in case the parameter contains certain characters that have special meaning in batch, so try `if "%~1"=="" call :finish 4`

Comment: For additional clarity open a Command Prompt window, type `call /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key. You clearly already know that as long as extensions are enabled, _(they are by default)_, that you can pass arguments to a label within the script, but the important part is that it shows you how those arguments are defined. You will note that the arguments are preceded by one percent character, they are not enclosed between percent characters. It should also explain what `%~1` means as used in the comment above.

Comment: Replace `goto donothing` by `goto :donothing` and you'll get the same issue…

Answer (score 3):

If you wonder why the `call :label` fails, but `goto label` works...

It's because of the straying percent sign
The expression `%1%` will be evaluated to `%1` and a single `%`.
The trailing percent is used as the start character for a variable.
When no other percent sign in the line can be found, only the percent sign is removed but the remaining line will be used unchanged.
But in your case of `call :label` the colon is used as special variable syntax, the part from the percent up to the colon is the variable name, but there isn't a variable named `NOTSET==NOTSET call` , therefore this part will be removed from the line and you got the line:

```
if :finish 4
```

This isn't a valid syntax for an `IF` statement